# What is the "authorindex" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorindex) under this tag refer to bibliographies, others to indexes -- perhaps it could be an alias to [indexing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing) (or be burninated altogether)?

Comment: `authorindex` provides basically an index to all cited authors (or a list of authors, in alphabetic sorting)

Answer (score 6):

`authorindex` is a [LaTeX package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing/authorindex?lang=en). I have retagged all questions that do not relate specifically to that package.